# Union all support in ServiceStack ORM lite 4.5.4

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In my application user can define multiple filters for specific type. I would like to somehow combine these queries in single one.

```
SqlExpression<Notice> query1 = Db.From<Notice>(s=>s.param1 == 2);
// ...queries are more complicated but result type is same
SqlExpression<Notice> query2 = Db.From<Notice>(s=>s.param1 == 3 && s.param2 == 3);

SqlExpression<Notice> unionAll = query1.UnionAll(query2);
var result = Db.Select(unionAll);
```

Any idea how to implement this in Orm Lite (4.5.4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst there's no official API that lets you do this, you should be able to construct it with something like:

```
var sql = query1.ToSelectStatement()
          + " UNION ALL " +
          query2.ToSelectStatement();

var results = db.SqlList<Notice>(sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure adding a UnionAll method to ServiceStack would buy you much because both of the queries would be called separately anyway. I guess you could create an extension method for easy of use.

Anyhow, you could just call each separately and then use the AddRange method to append the second results to the first.

`var results = Db.Select(query1);
var results2 = Db.Select(query2);
results.AddRange(results2);`

Alternative to AddRange, if you need to exclude duplicates, you can use the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method. And if you want to create a new list and not mutate query1's results, you can use the [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) method. These two options are System.Linq extension methods on IEnumerable.